# Laravel: unclickable links inside @section

Tags: php, laravel

Actually I'm facing a weird problem today when I declare a link inside @section it becomes unclickable, but when I write it outside @section it works normally.
Example:

```
@section('content')
//unclickable
<a href="#example">link</a>
@endsection

@section('content')
@endsection
//clickable and works perfect
<a href="#example">link</a>
```

Comment: you need to mention section name which you've yield it.. `@section('sectionname')
 ... content
@endsection`

Comment: What is the name of that section?

Comment: I did it, it's just an example

Comment: The name of section is not the problem, I've just forgotten it when I was typing the post

Comment: I found the problem, I wasn't putting the z-index: -1 to my background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours I found the problem, I wasn't putting the z-index: -1 to my background

```
.background{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url("../images/logo.png") no-repeat 50% 76%;
    opacity: 0.1;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```